# Rounding off floats with ostringstream

Tags: c++, rounding, stringstream, ostringstream

I have an issue regarding conversion from float to c++ string using ostringstream. Here is my line:

```
void doSomething(float t)
{
    ostringstream stream; 
    stream << t;
    cout << stream.str();
}
```

when t has value -0.89999 it is round off to -0.9, but when it's value is 0.0999 or lesser than this say 1.754e-7, it just prints without round off. what can be the solution for this.

Comment: Why don't you pass the float directly to `cout`?

Comment: @In silico, actually i want to use that value at some point in my code.

Comment: @In silico, what actually you say does not work.

Comment: That's why it's a comment, not an answer. :-) I didn't know the `cout` is for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set the precision for ostringstream using [`precision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision)

e.g

```
stream.precision(3);
stream<<fixed;    // for fixed point notation
//cout.precision(3); // display only
stream << t;

cout<<stream.str();
```

Comment: i got solution for 0.0999, but for the number of 7.9e-08 i am still getting the same. so what can be the solution for this.

Comment: you need to set precision to the stream itself. i.e. stream.precision(3);

Comment: i am doing the same. here is my code:ostringstream stream;
   stream.precision(1);
   stream << t;
   cout << endl<<"Value:"<< stream.str();

Comment: okay, use a fixed precision. e.g, stream.precision(8); stream << fixed; stream << t; cout << endl<<"Value:"<< stream.str();

Comment: What is the default precision for ostringstream?

Comment: For `float{32}` it seems to me that this prints `32` and not `32.00`: am I wrong?

Answer (score 7):

If you want a particular number of significant figures displayed try using setprecision(n) where n is the number of significant figures you want.

```
#include <iomanip>

void doSomething(float t)
{
    ostringstream stream; 
    stream << std::setprecision(4)  << t;
    cout <<  stream.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want fixed-point instead of scientific notation, use [`std::fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/):

```
stream << std::fixed << t;
```

Additionally you might want to set the precision as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use [setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/):

```
stream << setprecision(5) <<t ;
```

Now, your string `stream.str()` will be of the required precision.

Comment: i got solution for 0.0999, but for the number of 7.9e-08 i am still getting the same. so what can be the solution for this.